# Easiest way to deploy with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to have something similar to generic docker containers updating process:

```
docker-compose pull projectname:latest
docker-compose run projectname:latest
```

Is there any possibility to do that? Or I definitely need to store `docker-compose.yaml` on the target host?

Or is there any other ways to deploy linked containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at the moment. Docker Compose is a client tool, it just parses the local YAML file and sends `docker` commands to the Engine.

We will have the ability to create [Distributed Application Bundles](https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-app-bundle/) soon - this is available in the experimental branch now.

On your client where the YAML is, you'll be able to create an app bundle:

```
docker-compose bundle
```

Then you can deploy the bundle onto the Engine. [Check the roadmap](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26876) for that feature to see when it's coming into the main release.